# When to use 'classes' vs 'className' with Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm a little confused with the two properties. If I have,

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  style: {
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
  },
}));
```

Then, I can do,

```
const classes = useStyles();

<SomeComponent className={classes.style} />
```

But I can also do,

```
const classes = useStyles();

<SomeComponent classes={classes} />
```

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Will it apply the classname when you use `classes`?

Comment: Hope you include the imports also

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a very confusing aspect of MUI, but once you get it - it's super easy.

Consider that YOU are writing a component, and style it using JSS:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  in: {
    padding: 8
  }
}));

function MyComponent(){
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Outside className={classes.root}>
      <Inside className={classes.in} />
    </Outside>
  )
}
```

Notice that the component is essentially a composition (or a hierarchy) of components - `Outside` and `Inside` in this minimal example, but MUI components often have more than two (styled) nested components.

Now you want to export this component as part of a library and allow developers to style all the components involved (both `Outside` and `Inside`). How would you do it?

What MUI does, is it allows you to provide a `classes` property (you'll see in the docs each component's rule names - `root` and `in` in our example) that will be *merged* into MUI's own rules, or stylesheet if you wish (in the [MUI code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/4fba0dafd30f608937efa32883d151ba01fc9681/packages/material-ui/src/Checkbox/Checkbox.js#L181) this is done using the [withStyles HOC](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#withstyles)).

For convenience, every component also accepts `className` property that is merged into the className of the root element (`Outside` in our case).

Comment: great explanation

Answer (score 10):

`className` is always applied to the root element of the component whereas `classes` gives you deeper access to style child elements of the component via the object key of the style object. It's explained in the documentation here:

https://material-ui.com/customization/components/

Answer (score 7):

> When the **className** property isn't enough, and you need to access
>   deeper elements, you can take advantage of the **classes** object property
>   to customize all the CSS injected by Material-UI for a given
>   component.

More info: https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes

Answer (score 7):

both are for apply styles with some differences:
**`className`** property:

- it is for classes that you defined and wrote.
- it is always applied to the root element.

but

**`classes`** property:

- uses for overrides global classes name that defined in Material UI.
- just uses for Material UI components and it has no effect on the components you created.
- it uses for access to deeper and nested elements. (unlike the `className` that applied to the root element)
  for example, override `MuiButton-label` in the global classes material UI

```
.
.
.

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    label: {
        color: "#fff"
    }
}));

.
.
.

const classes = useStyles()

.
.
.

<Button classes={{ label: 'my-class-name' }} />
```

source: [documentation for more information](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/)

[image: dev tools]