# Confusion in using the "classes" prop in React MaterialUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am learning React and MUI. I was trying to follow the steps given [here](https://medium.com/@modularcoder/reactjs-multi-level-sidebar-navigation-menu-with-typescrip-materialui-251943c12dda) to create a sidebar. The guide uses `makeStyles` which is not compatible with React18. So, I tried something like the following:

```
    import * as React from "react";
    import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
    import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
    import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";
    import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
    import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
    
    const drawerWidth = 240;
    
    const SideBar = () => {
      const theme = useTheme();
    
      const drawerPaper = {
        position: "relative",
        backgroundColor: "#535454",
        color: "#fff",
        whiteSpace: "nowrap",
        paddingTop: theme.spacing(4),
        paddingBottom: theme.spacing(4),
        width: drawerWidth,
      };
    
    return (
        <Box className="root">
          <CssBaseline />
          <Drawer variant="permanent" classes={{ paper: drawerPaper }}>
            <Typography>I am a SideBar</Typography>
          </Drawer>
        </Box>
      );
    };
    
    export default SideBar;
```

This does not work. The `css` does not show up. Can someone tell me how I can do it? I also couldn't find much documentation on how to use the classes prop. A link to the documentation would also be helpful.

**Edit:**

I have already tried using `sx` as suggested by @Ippizinidev and @Hamed Siaban. That doesn't work. Using `sx`, I get the [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-nova-xhlnbb?file=/src/App.js) result. But I want something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-dew-ukf6im?file=/src/App.js). In the second example, I have put the css in a separate `.css` file. But I can't use `useTheme` from this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `makeStyles()`, You can use `useStyles()`.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60522631/when-to-use-classes-vs-classname-with-material-ui) for how to use this approach.

But in your case it's better if You use `sx` property.
So your code would be:

```
<Drawer variant="permanent" sx={drawerPaper}>
  <Typography>I am a SideBar</Typography>
</Drawer>
```